# Read text file using java , eclipse kepler

Tags: java, jsp, bufferedreader, eclipse-kepler

I am novice in Java and I am currently working in Eclipse Kepler. I have a JSP page from where I am reading a text file which is continuously being written using a shell script.

```
                <b>
                    <%
                        String filePath = "/home/default/test.txt";
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;

                        while((line = reader.readLine()) != "Success"){
                            sb.append(line+"\n");
                            out.println(sb.toString());
                        }                       
                    %>
                </b>
```

I need the logic to keep reading the log until it reads the final "Success" string and until it doesn't, it should not print any blank rows.

How to solve it?

Comment: `"!=" != ".equals()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            if (line.equals("Success")) {
                break; 
            } else {
                // perform required operation
            }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As epoch said, "!=" is not the same as "equals()". If you are comparing `Strings` always use "equals()".

```
while(!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("Success")) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("Success")) {
    if (line.trim().length() != 0) {
       out.println(line+"\n");
    }
}
```

The `line` is passed directly to the `out` stream. The use of StringBuilder is not obvious here.

Comment: i understand but would this code waits till it finds "Success" string coz before that i don't wanna exit the loop

Comment: If the code finds "Success", it will exit the loop. Otherwise, it will print out any non blank line.

Comment: @user728630 of course it would, because until it founds Success string it stays inside the loop and the line variable gets every time different value which is the next line of your text document. And to mention, it would be better to compare the line using .equals() method.